# How to get command substitution to work with string concatenation?

Tags: bash

I'm having a weird issue, and I'm not sure why. I believe it may be related to command substitution, but I don't have enough experience to understand why.

Take this script for example:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

MAJOR_VER="$(grep "version.major" application.properties | cut -d'=' -f2)"
MINOR_VER="$(grep "version.minor" application.properties | cut -d'=' -f2)"
PATCH_VER=3

echo ${MAJOR_VER}
echo ${MINOR_VER}
echo ${PATCH_VER}

echo "${MAJOR_VER}.${MINOR_VER}.${PATCH_VER}"
```

I am getting the results:

```
1
2
3
.3
```

So the first three echo calls are giving the correct information; however, whenever I try to concatenate them together, I only get the the last one to show up. I'm going to guess this is directly related to command substitution because if I hard code in the values for MAJOR_VER and MINOR_VER I get the expected results. Can someone please explain to me what I'm doing wrong here? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

File `application.properties` has dos line endings. Convert it with:

```
dos2unix application.properties
```

Observe the experiment:

```
$ cat script.sh 
#!/usr/bin/env bash

MAJOR_VER="$(grep "version.major" application.properties | cut -d'=' -f2)"
MINOR_VER="$(grep "version.minor" application.properties | cut -d'=' -f2)"
PATCH_VER=3

echo ${MAJOR_VER}
echo ${MINOR_VER}
echo ${PATCH_VER}

echo "${MAJOR_VER}.${MINOR_VER}.${PATCH_VER}"

$ cat application.properties 
version.major=1
version.minor=2

$ cat -A application.properties 
version.major=1^M$
version.minor=2^M$

$ ./script.sh 
1
2
3
.3

$ ./script.sh | cat -A
1^M$
2^M$
3$
1^M.2^M.3$

$ dos2unix application.properties 
dos2unix: converting file application.properties to Unix format ...

$ ./script.sh 
1
2
3
1.2.3
```

Answer (score 1):

This is probably because the `application.properties` has lines ending with `\r\n` instead of `\n`. What happens is the variables contain the `\r` at their end, that is, the value of `MAJOR_VER` is `1\r` and the value of `MINOR_VER` is `2\r`. When you `echo` them, the `\r` resets to the character position to the start of the line, and so the output of `echo "1\r.2\r.3"` will be printed as `.3`.

You could remove the `\r` using `tr -d`:

```
MAJOR_VER=$(grep "version.major" application.properties | cut -d'=' -f2 | tr -d '\r')
MINOR_VER=$(grep "version.minor" application.properties | cut -d'=' -f2 | tr -d '\r')
```

Comment: Awesome. Thank you!